# MySQL select all records who's timestamps fall within an "hour range", like between 11pm and 4am

Tags: mysql, sql, select, time, range

I have a table (`visits`) like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| vis_id       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| unit         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| time_in      | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| time_out     | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| in_username  | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| out_username | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I would like to be able to select ALL records who's `time_in` value falls between the hours of 11pm and 4am.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [hour](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) method:

```
SELECT * FROM visits WHERE HOUR(time_in) >= 11 AND HOUR(time_in) < 16
```

You will need a function to substract the time. If you know the date you should use a between function with date and time. So the MySQL index will be used aswell. With this method `HOUR` it will not use the index and if the query will be heavy it will take a short period.

Comment: Thanks. Though the hours should be 23 and 4, for 11pm and 4am

Comment: I understand what  you're saying about the index not being used, but what do you mean by "you will need a function to subtract the time"?

Comment: I mean `HOUR()` in this case.

Comment: If the time is 11PM and 4AM, the above will not work. See the method posted by me

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from visits where hour(in_time)>=23 or hour(in_time)<4
```